# How to connect two models 'sale.order' and 'rental.wizard' data and save together in Odoo External API in XML-RPC using Python Flask frameork

Tags: python, odoo, xml-rpc, odoo-11, odoo-12

I've been using the Python Flask framework to write APIs from Odoo and I've come across an issue and got stuck there. The issue is while creating a rental order where when I'm creating a rental order the Model for the form is sale.order and I'm able to save the data using the API with this code.
`createRental = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'sale.order', 'create', [rentalObj])`
Here 'rentalObj' is the JSON object of all the data.

[image: This is the model 'sale.order']

but if I have to add the Pickup Date, Return Date, Lot number after selecting the product in the Order Line it's giving me a popup modal where I have to fill it, but that popup is having the model name of rental.wizard and I've been trying to fill the data parallelly to both sale.order & rental.wizard but I'm not able to as I can only create data in one model at a time.

[image: This is the model 'rental.wizard']

It'd be very helpful if you can help me solve this issue as I'm not getting answers on the internet.

So please provide me with a sample code in Python or a way to add data to both the models and link them to each other. Thanks in advance.

I've tried writing this code.

```
rentalObj = {
                'name': data['woo_commerce_order_id'],
                'partner_id': customer_data[0]['id'],
                'validity_date': modified_date_str, #Expiry Date
                'pricelist_id': 1,  # ID of the pricelist
                'is_rental_order': 1, #Is it Rental order or Sale order
                'order_line': [
                    (0, 0, {  
                        'product_id': 864,
                        'product_uom_qty': int(quantity[1])
                    }),
                ],
            }
            createRental = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'sale.order', 'create', [rentalObj])

            wizard_vals = {
                'product_id': createRental,
                'pickup_date': '2023-05-10',
                'return_date': '2023-05-20',
                'quantity': 1.0
            }
            wizard_id = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'rental.wizard', 'create', [wizard_vals])
            models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'sale.order', 'write', [[createRental], {'wizard_id': wizard_id}])
```

But I'm getting the error "ValueError: Invalid field wizard_id on model sale.order"

Comment: Odoo's XML-RPC API is very simple which means you can use every models "public" method if you have the access. But what you can't do is using onchange events or flows with wizards, which you can see in the client (browser). Instead you have to understand the flows and reconstruct them with simple method calls. I'm not sure what the rental wizard is doing at all, but i guess, there will be some new fields on sales oder lines, which have to be filled with correct values. So "getting" those values and writing them to `sale.order.line` could be a way.